# Why do I get the error 'Can't find string terminator "END_HTML" anywhere before EOF'?

Tags: html, perl, batch-file

I have the following Perl code:

```
          use strict;
          use warnings;
          use MIME::Lite;
          use HTML::Entities;
          use Time::localtime;
          use Sys::Hostname;

          my $ti = localtime;
          my ($day,$month,$year)=($ti->mday,$ti->fullmonth,$ti->year);
          my $HOSTNAME =hostname();

          my $greeting = <<END_HTML;     
          <p style="width:600px;margin:0 100px"><font face="Arial" size="3"><strong>$month $day, $year</strong></font></p><br>
          <p style="width:600px;margin:0 100px"><font face="Arial" size="3" color="#3a7df9"><strong>Status of Update on '$HOSTNAME' machine</strong></font></p><br>
          END_HTML
          my $html = '<table style="width:600px;margin:0 100px" border="1" BORDERCOLOR="#000000">
          <thead><th bgcolor="#9fc0fb">Successful Update</th><th bgcolor="#9fc0fb">Failed Update</th></thead>
          <tbody>';
```

It works fine in Eclipse, but when I try running it from a Windows batch file, it fails with the error:

> Can't find string terminator "END_HTML" anywhere before EOF

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your entire script really indented like that? The end-of-string identifier for your here-doc can't be indented.

Comment: removing the indentation cleared the issue.Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3C_EOF_), there should not be any space before or after `END_HTML`:

> The terminating string must appear by itself (unquoted and with no surrounding whitespace) on the terminating line.

Clearing out the indentation removed the error.